# SQL Ranking Based on State and City

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image: Sample Output Image]

I have two datasets. First contains State Name, City Name and Other Contains Temperature information. How can I rank by State then rank by city over temperature?

```
select RANK() over(order by AVG(Average_Temp) desc) State_Rank_Temp, aqs_sites.State_Name, 
       RANK() over(partition by State_Name order by AVG(Average_Temp) desc) City_Rank, aqs_sites.City_Name, AVG(Temperature.Average_Temp) Average 
from aqs_sites INNER JOIN
    Temperature
     ON (aqs_sites.State_Code=Temperature.State_Code AND 
         aqs_sites.County_Code=Temperature.County_Code AND 
         aqs_sites.Site_Number=Temperature.Site_Num)
group by aqs_sites.City_Name, aqs_sites.State_Name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmmm.  You need an average at the state level *before* doing the ranking.  Here is one method:

```
select s.State_Name, 
       s.City_Name,
       avg(t.Average_Temp) as average 
       rank() over (partition by s.State_Name order by avg(t.Average_Temp) desc) as City_Rank, 
       dense_rank() over (order by avg(state_average))
from aqs_sites s INNER JOIN
     (select t.*, avg(Average_Temp) over (partition by state_code) as state_average
      from Temperature t
     ) t
     ON s.State_Code = t.State_Code AND 
        s.County_Code = t.County_Code AND 
        s.Site_Number = t.Site_Num
group by s.City_Name, s.State_Name;
```

Comment: The thing is there is no state column in Temperature to partition by and state_average is not contained in any aggregate function or groupby

Comment: @logdog . . . There is a state column, I just got the name wrong.  It is `state_code`.

Comment: *dense_rank() over (order by AVG(state_average) desc) City_Rank*..added AVG then it worked.. Thanks :)